Roslynator CLI. Include and Exclude parameters are not working
I am using Roslynator Command Line Tool version 0.8.7.0 (Roslyn version 4.9.0.0) and Windows 11
I want to analyze a specific file in my solution, I am using CLI for it.
I read a document on this page https://josefpihrt.github.io/docs/roslynator/cli.
I used next command roslynator analyze --exclude "**\*" --include "**\UserStatuses.cs"
The problem is that it analyzes a whole solution, instead of just one file. What am I doing worong?
